# Installing icons via gnome-tweaks crashed my system

Tags: icons, themes, gnome-shell

I installed gnome-tweaks today and tried installing some icons, but when I did, many of my icons disappeared and now those applications won't open. Even the terminal is dead; luckily I have another terminal program which works just as well as the Ubuntu terminal (I have Ubuntu 20.04) and with that I can open my applications. Still, I'd like to get things back to where they were.

If I try launching tweaks without `sudo`, it doesn't do anything and gives an error saying it could load the pixbuf from icon theme.

I tried launching tweaks with `sudo` and it opens, but whatever I do, it doesn't change things.

So, how can I take things back to standard without having to reinstall Ubuntu?

I'm kind of new in Ubuntu, so I'd appreciate detailed explanation. I can answer questions too. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, in case you stumble upon the same problem, just run:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

if you don't have `dconf` installed, then run:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```